# Interview question: remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list

Tags: c#, java, linked-list

I'm reading [Cracking the Coding Interview, Fourth Edition: 150 Programming Interview Questions and Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/145157827X) and I'm trying to solve the following question:

> 2.1 Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list. FOLLOW
>   UP: How would you solve this problem if
>   a temporary buffer is not allowed?

I'm solving it in C#, so I made my own `Node` class:

```
public class Node<T> where T : class
{
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Node(T value)
    {
        Next = null;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

My solution is to iterate through the list, then for each node to iterated through the remainder of the list and remove any duplicates (note that I haven't actually compiled or tested this, as instructed by the book):

```
public void RemoveDuplicates(Node<T> head)
{
    // Iterate through the list
    Node<T> iter = head;
    while(iter != null)
    {
        // Iterate to the remaining nodes in the list
        Node<T> current = iter;
        while(current!= null && current.Next != null)
        {
            if(iter.Value == current.Next.Value)
            {
                current.Next = current.Next.Next;
            }

            current = current.Next;
        }    

        iter = iter.Next;
    }
}
```

Here is the solution from the book (the author wrote it in java):

> Without a buffer, we can iterate with
>   two pointers: “current” does a normal
>   iteration, while “runner” iterates
>   through all prior nodes to check for
>   dups. Runner will only see one dup per
>   node, because if there were multiple
>   duplicates they would have been
>   removed already.

```
public static void deleteDups2(LinkedListNode head) 
{
    if (head == null) return;

    LinkedListNode previous = head;
    LinkedListNode current = previous.next;

    while (current != null) 
    {
        LinkedListNode runner = head;

        while (runner != current) { // Check for earlier dups
            if (runner.data == current.data) 
            {
                LinkedListNode tmp = current.next; // remove current
                previous.next = tmp;
                current = tmp; // update current to next node
                break; // all other dups have already been removed
            }
            runner = runner.next;
        }
        if (runner == current) { // current not updated - update now
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

So my solution always looks for duplicates for the current node to the end, while their solution looks for duplicates from the head to the current node. I feel like both solutions would suffer performance issues depending on how many duplicates there are in the list and how they're distributed (density and position). But in general: is my answer nearly as good as the one in the book or is it significantly worse?

Comment: List isn't an array, so you don't need a temporary buffer anyway :)

Comment: I think it will turn out to a better interview question to find a bug in the solution posted by the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you give a person a fish, they eat for a day.  If you teach a person to fish...

My measures for the quality of an implementation are:

- **Correctness**: If you aren't getting the right answer in all cases, then it isn't ready
- **Readability/maintainability**: Look at code repetition, understandable names, the number of lines of code per block/method (and the number of things each block does), and how difficult it is to trace the flow of your code.  Look at any number of books focused on refactoring, programming best-practices, coding standards, etc, if you want more information on this.
- **Theoretical performance** (worst-case and ammortized):  [Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is a metric you can use.  CPU and memory consumption should both be measured
- **Complexity**: Estimate how it would take an average professional programmer to implement (if they already know the algorithm).  See if that is in line with how difficult the problem actually is

As for your implementation:

- *Correctness*:  I suggest writing unit tests to determine this for yourself and/or debugging it (on paper) from start to finish with interesting sample/edge cases.  Null, one item, two items, various numbers of duplicates, etc
- *Readability/maintainability*:  It looks mostly fine, though your last two comments don't add anything.  It is a bit more obvious what your code does than the code in the book
- *Performance*:  I believe both are N-squared.  Whether the amortized cost is lower on one or the other I'll let you figure out :)
- *Time to implement*:  An average professional should be able to code this algorithm in their sleep, so looking good

Comment: @Lirik: Also, I haven't read the book you mentioned, but I have found Programming Interviews Exposed to be a good book.  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Interviews-Exposed-Secrets-Programmer/dp/047012167X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: I did consider both books, but after reading the reviews for both I decided to get "Cracking the Coding Interview." Note that both books have **REALLY good** ratings, so I had to decide based on the discussions about the content. It seems like Programming Interviews Exposed has a slightly more emphasis on the interview process (which I feel like I can ace easily, because I shower regularly hehe) and a little less on actual programming problems (which I tend to suffer on).

Comment: @Lirik: Sounds like you made the right book choice, then.  If you're actually interviewing, rather than doing algorithms for kicks, my best tip is to practice your problems on a white board.  If you can program standing up, talking out loud, in presentation style, then you probably won't even need to shower :)

Answer (score 4):

There's not much of a difference. If I've done my math right your's is on average N/16 slower than the authors but pleanty of cases exist where your implementation will be faster.

**Edit:**

I'll call your implementation Y and the author's A

Both proposed solutions has O(N^2) as worst case  and they both have a best case of O(N) when all elements are the same value.

**EDIT:**
This is a complete rewrite. Inspired by the debat in the comments I tried to find the average case for random N random numbers. That is a sequence with a random size and a random distribution. What would the average case be.

Y will always run U times where U is the number of unique numbers. For each iteration it will do N-X comparisons where X is the number of elements removed prior to the iteration (+1). The first time no element will have been removed and on average on the second iteration N/U will have been removed.

That is on average ½N will been left to iterate. We can express the average cost as
U*½N. The average U can be expressed based on N as well 0

Expressing A becomes more difficult. Let's say we use I iterations before we've encountered all unique values. After that will run between 1 and U comparisons (on average that's U/") and will do that N-I times.

I*c+U/2(N-I)

but whats the average number of comparisons (c) we run for the first I iterations. on average we need to compare against half of the elements already visited and on average we've visited I/2 elements, Ie. c=I/4

I/4+U/2(N-I).

I can be expressed in terms of N. On average we'll need to visited half on N to find the unique values so I=N/2 yielding an average of

(I^2)/4+U/2(N-I) which can be reduced to (3*N^2)/16.

That is of course if my estimation of the averages are correct. That is on average for any potential sequence A has N/16 fewer comparisons than Y but pleanty of cases exists where Y is faster than A. So I'd say they are equal when compared to the number of comparisons

Comment: You'll have hard time proving this claim. Not to mention, both solutions have asymptotical complexity O(n^2), so 'significantly' isn't applicable here.

Comment: @Rune, aside from Nikita's comment, I'd have to respond that: 1. The suggested solution does not exit when a duplicate is found, and 2. The suggested solution has to iterate from the beginning of the list to the current node. The suggested solution only exits when the current node has reached the end of the list (i.e. every time we move the current node, the runner has to run from the beginning of the list all the way to the current node, which seems to be the mirror action of what I'm doing).

Comment: @Lirik your post says it only looks for _ome_ duplicate because from the head to the node there can only be one. Why then continue?

Comment: Agree - while both have the same complexity the one that searches remainder of the list for duplicates is worse:

Comment: @Nikita nope it's not a hard proof and I've included it in my update

Comment: @Lirik btw the code you supplied from the book does in fact opt out when a duplicate is found: "break; // all other dups have already been removed"

Comment: @Rune Your argument is completely toothless. You state that Y iterates until the end every time ("Y does every time"), while you forget to mention Y does it only once. All elements with equal value will be removed in one pass.

Comment: A case where OP's solution does better, `abcd0000`. 30 against 33 (if you consider selecting current node to search for it as an operation). Anyway, as you noted, it's not a hard proof and it's not a proof at all: it's just speculations.

Comment: @Nikita there might be cases where Y performs better than A (which is also stated in my answer) abcd0000 is however not one of them (estimated from number of comparisons) they both use 25

Comment: @Rune _"there might be cases where Y performs better than A"_ That contradicts to a statement in your post and kinda brakes your whole theory. As for this example, as I noted in the previous comment, I was counting iterations of the outer loop too. Author's algorithm will have 8 of them, OP's - only 5.

Comment: @Rune FS In truth, I think OP's solution _might_ be slightly slower on average (or it might be other way around). But it's not evident from the algorithm and I don't think it should be used to discriminate one approach or another.

Comment: @Rune, Nikita: While this discussion is interesting and useful, you may want to think of the goal.  Formal proofs, no matter how simple, are not done in most interviews, unless you can whip them out very quickly.  Big-O is generally expected.  Decent rationalizations for minor differences in amortized cost are accepted, though.  This rationalization *looks* reasonable - The book answer may terminate early, but the OP compensates for that by removing all duplicates in one pass.  There is no representative sample data, so we can't properly profile.  Can we formally prove the true amortized cost?

Comment: @Nikita after digging deep I have to agree

Comment: @Rune FS, thanks for the thoughtful answer and the extensive research into the performance metrics.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a HashMap? This way it will take O(n) time and O(n) space. I will write psuedocode.

```
function removeDup(LinkedList list){
  HashMap map = new HashMap();
  for(i=0; i<list.length;i++)
      if list.get(i) not in map
        map.add(list.get(i))
      else
        list.remove(i)
      end
  end
end
```

Of course we assume that HashMap has O(1) read and write.

Another solution is to use a mergesort and removes duplicate from start to end of the list. This takes O(n log n)

mergesort is O(n log n)
removing duplicate from a sorted list is O(n). do you know why?
therefore the entire operation takes O(n log n)

Comment: The hash map is also provided as an example in the book (and is much better), but the hash map is considered to be the temporary buffer so for the follow up portion of the question a hash map cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

[Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is an [in-place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) sort. You could modify the "siftUp" or "siftDown" function to simply remove the element if it encounters a parent that is equal. This would be O(n log n)

```
function siftUp(a, start, end) is
 input:  start represents the limit of how far up the heap to sift.
               end is the node to sift up.
 child := end 
 while child > start
     parent := floor((child - 1) ÷ 2)
     if a[parent] < a[child] then (out of max-heap order)
         swap(a[parent], a[child])
         child := parent (repeat to continue sifting up the parent now)
     else if a[parent] == a[child] then
         remove a[parent]
     else
         return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is just as good as author's, only it has a bug in implementation :) Try tracing it on a list of two nodes with equal data.

Comment: I think I found the bug... I have to check if current is null in the second loop, because if there are only two nodes and I remove one, then the second time around the loop I will be attempting to reference a null object.

Comment: see my answer as to way the average case of the author's implementation is faster

Comment: i think it will be good interview question to find the bug in the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is simply specular to the book's! You go forward, the book goes backward. There is no difference as both of you scan all elements. And, yes, since no buffer is allowed, there are performance issues. You usually don't have to mind about performance with such costrained questions and when it's not explicitly required.

Interview questions are made to test your open mindness. I have doubts about Mark's answer: it definitely is the best solution in real-world examples, but even if these algorithms use constant space, the constraint that **no** temporary buffer is allowed must be respected.

Otherwise, I guess that the book would have adopted such an approach. Mark, please forgive me for being critic against you.

Anyway, just to go deeper in the matter, yours and the book's approach both require `Theta(n^2)` time, while Mark's approach requires `Theta(n logn) + Theta(n)` time, which results in `Theta(n logn)`. Why `Theta`? Because compare-swap algorithms are `Omega(n logn)` too, remember!

Comment: A small correction. "best solution in real-world" will probably use hash: linear time complexity and way easier to implement.

Comment: thanks for the great input! The book does offer two answers, the first one uses a hash map (which is definitely MUCH faster) and the second answer is provided for the follow up/challenge portion. I only posted the author's second answer, since the first one is somewhat simplistic.

Comment: The _worst_ case is the same but OPs average case equals the worst case that's not the case for the author's implementation where all previous elements will only be searched when there're no duplicates. If there's one duplicate on average only half of the priviously visited elements will be sought

Comment: @Rune: since you don't know how many duplicates are present, in the best case all elements are equal so you remove them all on the first scan (O(n)) and in the worst case there are no duplicates, so you scan *all* the previous/following elements, resulting in O(n^2), I said Theta and I might have been incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Code in java:

```
public static void dedup(Node head) {
    Node cur = null;
    HashSet encountered = new HashSet();

    while (head != null) {
        encountered.add(head.data);
        cur = head;
        while (cur.next != null) {
            if (encountered.contains(cur.next.data)) {
                cur.next = cur.next.next;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        head = cur.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the buffer if you are going to use a reference to a previous element `Node cur`. Just compare head within the second while to cur.next.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same in cpp. Please let me know your comments on this.

// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
struct node *tail = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

struct node* createNode(int data)
{
    struct node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head = newNode;
    return newNode;
}

bool insertAfter(node * list, int data)
{
    //case 1 - insert after head
    struct node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!list)
    {

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    struct node * curpos = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curpos = head;
    //case 2- middle, tail of list
    while (curpos)
    {
        if (curpos == list)
        {
            newNode->data = data;
            if (curpos->next == NULL)
            {
            newNode->next = NULL;
            tail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->next = curpos->next;
            }
            curpos->next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
        curpos = curpos->next;
    }
}

void deleteNode(node *runner, node * curr){

    //DELETE AT TAIL
    if (runner->next->next == NULL)
    {
        runner->next = NULL;        
    }
    else//delete at middle
    {
        runner = runner->next->next;
        curr->next = runner;
    }
    }


void removedups(node * list)
{
    struct node * curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    struct node * runner = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr = head;
    runner = curr;
    while (curr != NULL){
        runner = curr;
        while (runner->next != NULL){
            if (curr->data == runner->next->data){
                deleteNode(runner, curr);
            }
            if (runner->next!=NULL)
            runner = runner->next;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct node * list = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    list = createNode(1);
    insertAfter(list,2);
    insertAfter(list, 2);
    insertAfter(list, 3);   
    removedups(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in C:

```
    void removeduplicates(N **r)
    {
        N *temp1=*r;
        N *temp2=NULL;
        N *temp3=NULL;
        while(temp1->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp2=temp1;
            while(temp2!=NULL)
            {
                temp3=temp2;
                temp2=temp2->next;
                if(temp2==NULL)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if((temp2->data)==(temp1->data))
                {
                    temp3->next=temp2->next;
                    free(temp2);
                    temp2=temp3;
                    printf("\na dup deleted");
                }
            }
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in C

```
    void removeduplicates(N **r)
    {
        N *temp1=*r;
        N *temp2=NULL;
        N *temp3=NULL;
        while(temp1->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp2=temp1;
            while(temp2!=NULL)
            {
                temp3=temp2;
                temp2=temp2->next;
                if(temp2==NULL)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if((temp2->data)==(temp1->data))
                {
                    temp3->next=temp2->next;
                    free(temp2);
                    temp2=temp3;
                    printf("\na dup deleted");
                }
            }
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

C# Code for removing duplicates left after the first set of iteration:

```
 public Node removeDuplicates(Node head) 
    {
        if (head == null)
            return head;

        var current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.next != null && current.data == current.next.data)
            {
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
            else { current = current.next; }
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation using HashSet in `O(n)` time.

I have used a hashset to store unique values and 2 node-pointers to traverse through the linkedlist. If a duplicate is found, assign the value of current pointer to the previous pointer.

This will ensure removal of duplicate records.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list.
    /// </summary>
    class RemoveDups<T>
    {
        private class Node
        {
            public Node Next;
            public T Data;
            public Node(T value)
            {
                this.Data = value;
            }
        }

        private Node head = null;

        public static void MainMethod()
        {
            RemoveDups<int> rd = new RemoveDups<int>();
            rd.AddNode(15);
            rd.AddNode(10);
            rd.AddNode(15);
            rd.AddNode(10);
            rd.AddNode(10);
            rd.AddNode(20);
            rd.AddNode(30);
            rd.AddNode(20);
            rd.AddNode(30);
            rd.AddNode(35);

            rd.PrintNodes();
            rd.RemoveDuplicates();

            Console.WriteLine("Duplicates Removed!");
            rd.PrintNodes();
        }

        private void RemoveDuplicates()
        {
            //use a hashtable to remove duplicates
            HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>();
            Node current = head;
            Node prev = null;

            //loop through the linked list
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (hs.Contains(current.Data))
                {
                    //remove the duplicate record
                    prev.Next = current.Next;
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert element into hashset
                    hs.Add(current.Data);
                    prev = current;
                }
                current = current.Next;

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add Node at the beginning
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val"></param>
        public void AddNode(T val)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(val);
            newNode.Data = val;
            newNode.Next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Print nodes
        /// </summary>
        public void PrintNodes()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.Data);
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacker Rank Day24:More Linked Lists,Removing duplicate Node in C#.

```
static Node RemoveDuplicateNode(Node head)
    {
        Node Link = head;
        Node Previous;
        Node DulicateNode;
        int count = 0,temp;
        while (Link != null)
        {
            temp = Link.data;
            DulicateNode = Link;
            Previous = Link;
            while(DulicateNode != null)
            {
                if(DulicateNode.data==temp)
                {
                    Previous.data = DulicateNode.data;
                    Previous.next = DulicateNode.next;
                    ++count;
                }
                if(count>=2)
                {
                   if(DulicateNode.next != null)
                    {
                        DulicateNode.data = DulicateNode.next.data;
                        DulicateNode.next = DulicateNode.next.next;
                    }
                   else
                        DulicateNode=null;
                }
                else
                DulicateNode = DulicateNode.next;
            }
            count = 0;
            Link = Link.next;
        }
    
    
        return head;
    }
```