# Delete list of structures by field

Tags: c#, list, structure

I have a list in c#, that list contains structures, I would like to delete repeated structures, but just the structures which have some fields equal.
How Can I do?
thx

Comment: @Rubens Farias, not everything is homework you know. there are even stupid/trivial/easy things in business and sometimes even the top programmers might miss them.

Comment: Can you clarify with an example, not sure if I get the requirement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542600/interview-question-remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>(new[]
{
    new Sample {Id = 1},
    new Sample {Id = 1},
    new Sample {Id = 2},
    new Sample {Id = 3},
    new Sample {Id = 1}
});

var duplicates = samples
    .Select    ((s, i) => new { s.Id, Index = i })  // Get item key and index
    .GroupBy   (s => s.Id)                          // Group by Key
    .Where     (g => g.Count() > 1)                 // Get duplicated ones
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip (1)                     // We'll keep first one
                      .Select(i => i.Index))        // Get other items ids
    .Reverse();
foreach (var index in duplicates)
{
    samples.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solution:

1. Remove the duplicates by hand: meaning iterate through the list with a nested loop.
2. Assign the struct a hash code and equality check and use a `Hashset<YourStruct>` to remove the duplicates. This can be done by a custom `IEqualityComparer` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)) implementation or if you "own" the struct by implementing the `IEquatable` interface with appropriate `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method overriding.

If your set is small and this operation has to be done once in your code, I would go for solution one. But if this comparison logic is used over and over again I would go for solution two.

Implementation for solution two:

```
    struct YourStruct
    {
       public int Id; 
    }

    class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<YourStruct>
    {

      public bool Equals(YourStruct a, YourStruct b)
      {
        return a.Id == b.Id;
      }


      public int GetHashCode(YourStruct s)
      {
        return s.Id;
      }

    }

    List<YourStruct> list = new List<YourStruct>();

    HashSet<YourStruct> hs = new HashSet<YourStruct>(list, new Comparer());
```

Comment: thx!, and if wanted to compare objects from a class instead of structures¿?

Comment: about the same. As long as you implement your own `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.